# how to set allowLinking tomcat attribute value from the java code

Tags: java, tomcat

is there a proper way to set the value of the attribute allowLinking in the context.xml file of the tomacat I'm using from a java code.
i have tried something like:

public class myServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
             ........
    try {
        .......
        getServletContext().setAttribute("allowLinking", true);
```

TNX

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are trying to do in java code. The reason is that Tomcat reads the allowLinking configuration setting before any web application code runs. There is a way to get hold of the Context object you need (note it isn't the same as the ServletContext) but that won't help you.

The simplest way to do what you want is include a META-INF/context.xml file with your web application that sets the allowLinking property.

I am assuming you have read the docs for this option and are aware of the security implications of enabling it.

Comment: And if i change it during runtime? the changes won't affects?
I've noticed that this variable is changeable from the mbeans

Comment: Correct. If you change that on the Context at runtime nothing will happen.